# ¿Es posible optimizar la búsqueda de codificación/descodificación con chardet?

Tags: python, python-3.x

buenas tardes:

Mi consulta va en relación al siguiente código:

```
def obtener_codificacion():
    with open(buscarchivo, 'rb') as a:
        datos = a.read()
    return detect(datos)['encoding']
```

He notado que cuando realizo la apertura de archivo txt tiende a ralentizarse, y en la lectura de un libro, por ejemplo: "Don Quijote de la Mancha" en un archivo de texto plano con 1,7 millones de palabras, **se demora**. Archivos más grandes podrían demorar más, o complicarse aún más en otra clase de archivos. ¿Es necesariamente un problema, está dentro de lo esperado, no hay otra alternativa?

El programa en cuestión es este:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
from chardet import detect


def obtener_codificacion():
    with open(buscarchivo, 'rb') as a:
        datos = a.read()
    return detect(datos)['encoding']


while True:
    cont = 0
    while cont < 3:
        buscarchivo = input('Ingrese el nombre del archivo para abrir: ')
        try:
            archivo = open(buscarchivo, 'r', encoding=obtener_codificacion())
            lineabusca = input('Ingrese frase/palabra a buscar: ')
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            cont += 1
            print(f'El archivo no se ha encontrado\nIntento {cont} de 3')
    suma = 0
    try:
        for linea in archivo:
            linea = linea.rstrip()
            if re.search(lineabusca, linea):
                suma += 1
        archivo.close()
        print(suma)
    except NameError:
        print('Pruebe haciendo una búsqueda manual del archivo\nY luego a reingresar el nombre.')
    while True:
        vuelta = input('¿Desea realizar otra búsqueda?\n(S/sí - N/no): ').upper()
        if vuelta == 'S':
            break
        elif vuelta == 'N':
            break
    if vuelta == 'N':
        print('Hasta pronto!')
        break
```

De antemano, gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto podría servir:

```python
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

def obtener_codificacion():
    detector = UniversalDetector()
    with open(buscarchivo, 'rb') as a:
        datos = a.read(1)
        detector.feed(datos)
        if detector.done: break
    detector.close()
    return detector.result['encoding']

# ...
```

Este código está basado en [este ejemplo](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-detecting-encoding-incrementally) de la documentación de chardet.

Según esta documentación, el `UniversalDetector` es la forma recomendada de trabajar con grandes cantidades de texto. Los datos son pasados al `UniversalDetector` a través del método `feed()`. Cuando el detector alcanza un umbral mínimo de confianza el atributo `done` se establece en `True`.

En lugar de leer totalmente el archivo al usar `read()` debe ser más eficiente leer byte por byte usando `read(1)` e ir pasando cada byte leído al detector hasta que sea suficiente como para obtener la codificación.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Con algunas pequeñas modificaciones, mejoró notablemente la velocidad de lectura.